# How release Promise pending with async-await in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, openapi

my Code :

```
const attList = async (areaCode, cityCode) => {
    const url = `http://api.visitkorea.or.kr/openapi/service/rest/KorService/areaBasedList?ServiceKey=${serviceKey}&contentTypeId=12&areaCode=${areaCode}&numOfRows=40&sigunguCode=${cityCode}&MobileOS=ETC&MobileApp=AppTest`;
    try {
        const {data:res} = await axios.get(url)
        const list = res.response.body.items.item;
        return list
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

console.log(attList(1, 1))
```

on Console :
[image]

PromiseResult is Allright, but I don't know how release PromiseResult from Promise{}

Comment: `console.log(attList(1, 1))` -----> `attList(1, 1).then(data => console.log(data))`. You should also _throw_ the error from the `catch` block of `attList` function: `console.log(err);` ----> `throw error;`. Alternatively, you could remove the `try-catch` block and add the catch method in the code that calls this function: `attList(1, 1).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(...)`

Comment: Your `attList` function returns a `Promise`, which you, in order to use it, either need to `await` in async code, or chain with a `.then()` in sync code.

Comment: `attList` is async function, so you can wait till promise fulfilled and get it's result using `const result = await attList(1, 1)` or `await attList(1,1).then(result => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

**Async functions always return a promise**. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise. Note: Even though the return value of an async function behaves as if it's wrapped in a Promise. resolve, they are not equivalent.

```js
const attList = async (areaCode, cityCode, serviceKey) => {
  const url = `http://api.visitkorea.or.kr/openapi/service/rest/KorService/areaBasedList?ServiceKey=${serviceKey}&contentTypeId=12&areaCode=${areaCode}&numOfRows=40&sigunguCode=${cityCode}&MobileOS=ETC&MobileApp=AppTest`;

  const _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

  try {
    const data = await axios.get(url);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

attList(1, 1, null);
```

you didn't define serviceKey so I couldn't test it with your URL, but I assure you the syntax is just fine.